# jBPM integration on WebSphere with oracle 10g as datasource

Tags: websphere, jbpm

I am new to JBoss - jbpm . The thing i need to inquire is how to integrate jbmp with my application deployed on websphere with oracle 10g as the datasource . Is there any tutorial that can help me as i couldn't find one . Secondly which version of jbpm would be best for me to achieve the above integration . Any sort of help wpuld be highly appreciated . Thanks !

Comment: From my experience , use the latest 5.4 snapshot version . 5.3.0 Final version has some bugs .